# Why user snapshot cannot show event log in google analytics?website with gtm

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, snapshot

Why user snapshot cannot show event log in google analytics?
My application is website with using GTM,and not use firebase,just use gtm and google analytics.
Debugview is working properly，and realtime report also works properly.
Thank you!